# How can i conditionally use an ajax call to retrieve Jquery Datatables data?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatables

We are using jQuery Datatables in our page. The table data is loaded with ajax calls. However, I only want to load the data if a certain condition is met. When the condition is not met, an empty datatable will be shown.

Below is the table as it is now. It works fine and loads the data correctly, but I haven't added the condition yet. The condition will be `if (@Model.SelectedOrganizationId != null, load the data'`Else, display an empty table`.

I could have two table initializations--one with data population and one without, but that seems repetitive. Also I could possibly just return null to the ajax call, but that seems unnecessary.(As in, why make the call if I don't have to?)

****************Edit***************************************************

**Basically, I'd like to initialize an empty table and load the data after, if the condition is met.**

```
       function GetUnassignedActiveRolesGrid(showOnlyDistrictRoles)
    {
        /* Unassigned Active Roles */
        unassignedActiveRolesGrid = $("#gridUnassignedActiveRoles").DataTable({
            fixedHeader: true,
            createdRow: function ( table  ) {
                setTabIndex(table);
            },
            processing: true,
            info: true,
            stateSave: false,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUnassignedActiveRoles", "UserAccount")',
                data: {accountId: @Model.UserNameDetails.AccountId, organizationId: '@Model.SelectedOrganizationId', showOnlyDistrictRoles: showOnlyDistrictRoles},
                dataSrc: "",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON"
            },
            paging: false,
            searching: true,
            autoWidth: false, // Disable the auto width calculation,
            language: {
                emptyTable: "Sorry, no role data available"
            },
            columns: [
                {data:  "ModuleName", title: "Module"},
                {data:  "Label", title: "Role"},
                {data:  "Description", title: "Description" },
                {title: "Navigation", className: "center"},
                {data:  "ModuleSortOrder", title: "ModuleSortOrder" },
                {data:  "RoleSortOrder", title: "RoleSortOrder" }
            ],
            order: [[4, "asc"], [5, "asc"], [0, "asc"], [1, "asc"]],
            columnDefs: [
                { width: "20%", targets: [0,1] },
                { width: "50%", targets: 2 },
                { width: "10%", targets: 3 },
                { orderable: false, targets: [2] },
                { orderable: false, targets: [3] },
                { targets: 3, data:
                    function(role) {
                        return role.OrganizationId == '@Model.SelectedOrganizationId' ? "<a class='link_UnassignedActive_Add' href='#anchorUnassignedActiveRoles'>Add</a>" : "";
                    }},
                { visible: false, searchable: false, targets: [4,5] }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: The plan you have outlined sounds fine. What exact problem are you having? Where are you using your `if (@Model.SelectedOrganizationId != null), load the data; Else, display an empty table`

Comment: You are overengineering. Make the request and let the server return the data that fits the request. Which might be something, or it might be nothing. Don't overthink saving a single Ajax request until that time where it becomes a measurable problem, that's what I would say.

Comment: If you want to knock yourself out, write a custom function as the Ajax data source (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: ok I just thought there might be a simple way to do it, but i will do as you suggest.